# Plotting every row of data as a separate graph

Tags: r, plot

I have a 7 column tab-separated file like this:

```
Name    Length  name2   Sum1    Sum2    FP  RC
X1  10  gene1   39  24  0.32    18 3640 315 1913 2907 1495 281 130 455 239
X2  6  gene2   8  43  0.19    10 20 30 40 50 33 22 12
```

The 7th column `RC` has multiple values separated by spaces. The number of values in the 7th column for each row is equal to the number in the 2nd column `Length`. For example, in the row starting with X1 the 2nd column indicates there are 10 values in the 7th column.

I want to plot a graph for each row and I want to save them as 2 separate graphs gene1.pdf and gene2.pdf.

The x axis would have a range of values 1 through 10 (taking row X1 as an example) and the y axis would be 18, 3640, etc.

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hers's the answer

**# Loop through the rows of the yeast_table and plot**

```
for (i in 1:nrow(yeast_table)){
  #open a pdf file 
  pdf(file=paste(yeast_table[i,3],".pdf",sep=""),width=10,height=5)
  counts <- as.numeric(strsplit(yeast_table[i,7], " ")[[1]])
  vec <- 1:yeast_table[i,2]
  plot(vec,counts,type="l",main=yeast_table[i,3],xlab="CODON",ylab="COVERAGE",col="blue")
  #close the pdf file
  dev.off()
}
```